# In my vim ( under colorscheme molokai), my listchars( vertical bar) is weird

Tags: vim, color-scheme

[image]

My related setting is :

```
colorscheme  molokai
set  listchars=tab:\|\
```

All I really need is a real "vertical bar",
but  `molokai` show it close to a "slash".

Under other  colorscheme,  it's  normal.

What  should  I do?

[image]

Comment: Though this is technically a question for SuperUser, i'd like to know the answer too :)

Comment: Are you sure you set "set listchars=\|\"? As expected it does not work on my system. Is it set listchars=tab:\|\ ?

Answer (score 0):

Works as expected for me with the following setting

```
set list
set listchars=tab:\|\
```

listchars tab requires two character like `>-`, `>` is displayed at starting of <kbd>tab</kbd> and remaining is filled by second character `-`

So `\|\` is actually `|` and `space` character escaped by `\`. Hence, you will required to put a space after `\|\`

Comment: yes, I have put a space after \|\, It's "\|\ " .   but  "|" just looks very close to "/"  under  molokai  scheme,  very  weried!  all  the other  is OK.

Comment: How you set listachars, you are missing the `tab` in your question?

Comment: I'm sorrry, I missed  "tab" in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Now I konw why this happend.

Just to disable this in molokai/colors/molokai.vim 
:hi SpecialKey gui=Italic

Because italic font make verbical bar "|" close to slash"/"

There is my current setting,  :hi SpeciakKey gui=bold

I hope this will help you!